# Is it possible to add a TextView to an Adapter Class and store the result in an Activity Class

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am using a custom Adapter Class and want to add a TextView to it and display in a simple Activity

[image]

```
User_cart.java  it is my activity

public class User_Cart extends FragmentActivity 
{
    CartAdapter adapter;
    ListView listview;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    public static String DISH_NAME;
    public static String DISH_COST;
    public static String DISH_QUANTITY;
    Button order_btn;
    TextView result;
    Double quantitySTRtemp, costSTRtemp, totalSTR, subtotalSTR;
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_cart);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subtotalET);

        order_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.orderBT);

        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        List<Order> orders = db.getAllOrders();

        Log.d("tot", "" + db.getOrdersCount());
//db.deleteall();
        for (Order cn : orders) {

            String log = "Id: " + cn.getID() + " ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Cost: " + cn.getCost() + " Quantoty: " + cn.getQuantity();
            // Writing Contacts to log
           /* DISH_NAME = cn.getName();
            DISH_COST = cn.getCost();
            DISH_QUANTITY = cn.getQuantity();*/

            Log.d("Name: ", log);
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("name", cn.getName());
            map.put("cost", cn.getCost());
            map.put("quantity", cn.getQuantity());
            arraylist.add(map);
            //  listview.getSelectedItem();

        }
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userlistview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new CartAdapter(User_Cart.this, arraylist);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.menus_toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.backbutton);
        calculateSum();
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        order_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            boolean showText = false;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(User_Cart.this, "Thank You For order", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                db.deleteall();
                Intent intent = new Intent(User_Cart.this, MainActivity.class);


                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        //FragmentManager fm = User_Cart.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        // fm.popBackStack();
        //getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public void calculateSum() {
        double sum = 0;
        List<Order> orders = db.getAllOrders();
        for (Order cn : orders) {


            try {
                //quantitySTR = new Double(et_dish_quan.getText().toString());
                quantitySTRtemp = Double.valueOf(cn.getQuantity());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                quantitySTRtemp = 0.0; // your default value
            }

            try {
                //costSTR = new Double(et_menucost.getText().toString());
                costSTRtemp =Double.valueOf(cn.getCost());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                costSTRtemp = 0.0; // your default value
            }
            Double resultSTR = quantitySTRtemp * costSTRtemp;


            sum = sum + (resultSTR);
        }
       Log.d("sum",""+sum);
    }

**CartAdapter.java**

 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
        // Declare Variables

        final TextView et_menuname, et_menucost, et_dish_quan;
        Button btn_increment, btn_decrement;
        final TextView totalET, costET, QuantityET;
        ImageView img_dishtype;
        final String rupee;
        rupee = context.getString(R.string.Rs);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.usercustomlistview, parent, false);
        resultp = data.get(position);
        btn_increment = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.increment_btn);
        btn_decrement = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.decrement_btn);
        totalET = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ptotal);
        et_menuname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Dish_NameET);
        et_menucost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dish_costET);
        et_dish_quan = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Dish_quantityET);

        et_menuname.setText(resultp.get("name"));
        et_menucost.setText(resultp.get("cost"));
        et_dish_quan.setText(resultp.get("quantity"));
        try {
            //quantitySTR = new Double(et_dish_quan.getText().toString());
            quantitySTR = Double.parseDouble(et_dish_quan.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            quantitySTR = 1.0; // your default value
        }
        try {
            //costSTR = new Double(et_menucost.getText().toString());
            costSTR = Double.parseDouble(et_menucost.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            costSTR = 1.0; // your default value
        }
        resultSTR = costSTR * quantitySTR;

        stringdouble = Double.toString(resultSTR);
        totalET.setText(stringdouble);

        empname = (resultp.get("name"));

        btn_increment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            boolean showText = false;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resultp = data.get(position);


                counter += 1;
                showText = true;
                if (counter == 1 || counter < 1) {
                    et_dish_quan.setText("1");
                } else {
                    et_dish_quan.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                }

                try {
                    quantitySTR = new Double(et_dish_quan.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    quantitySTR = 1.0; // your default value
                }
                try {
                    costSTR = new Double(et_menucost.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    costSTR = 1.0; // your default value
                }
                resultSTR = costSTR * quantitySTR;
                final String stringdouble = Double.toString(resultSTR);
                totalET.setText(stringdouble);
                //db.updateOrder(TABLE_ORDERS, cv, "_id=" + id, null);
               tempcost = Double.toString(costSTR);
               tempquan = Double.toString(counter);

                db.addOrder(new Order(empname, tempcost, tempquan));
            }
        });
        btn_decrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            boolean showText = false;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resultp = data.get(position);
                counter--;
                showText = true;
                if (counter == 1 || counter < 1) {
                    et_dish_quan.setText("1");
                } else {
                    et_dish_quan.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                }
                try {
                    quantitySTR = new Double(et_dish_quan.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    quantitySTR = 1.0; // your default value
                }
                try {
                    costSTR = new Double(et_menucost.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    costSTR = 1.0; // your default value
                }
                resultSTR = costSTR * quantitySTR;
                final String stringdouble = Double.toString(resultSTR);
                totalET.setText(stringdouble);
                tempcost = Double.toString(costSTR);
               tempquan = Double.toString(counter);

                db.addOrder(new Order(empname,tempcost,tempquan));
                Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                //uc.calculateSum();

            }

        });
        return itemView;
    }
```

sum of litiview item(resultSTR). i want to do addtion of resutstr. i am getting total value of cost and quantity.

Comment: *addition of custom adapter text view*? what do yo mean? Please post some code.

Comment: check the image which i shared i want to perform subtotal but my total in custom adapter class and subtotal in simple class

Answer (score 2):

```
//Your Activity class will be like this:-

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> listValues;
    ListView listView;
    TextView textView;
      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            listValues=new ArrayList<String>();
            listValues.add("1");
            listValues.add("2");
            listValues.add("3");
            listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            customAdapter= new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.myview, listValues);
            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }

    //Create a method like below in your activity class

        public void updateValue(String amount)
        {
        textView.setText(amount);
        }
```

Your adapter will be like this:-

```
    private ArrayList<Currency> values;
    private Context context;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                           ArrayList<String> values) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
            this.values=values;
            this.context=context;
    }

     @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner, parent, false);
            tempValues = null;
            tempValues = values.get(position);
            TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvLabel);
            Button button=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.convert);
            label.setText(values.get(position));
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int calculatedValue=Integer.parseInt(label.getText().toString())*2;
                    if(context instanceof MainActivity)
                    {
    //Update your calculated value in activity textview    
    ((MainActivity)context).update(String.valueOf(calculatedValue));
                }
            }
        });
        return row;
    }
```

Comment: my adapter and class are different and  want to calculate total in adapter class and show it in normal class

Comment: You can use the above snippet for the same. Let me know in case you need full code example.

Comment: You can store the values of your list item's edittext in an arraylist and then on some event(like button click or focus change) you can calculate the sum from the arraylist and update in activity textview.

Comment: you can see in image qun*cost=total , want to suom of (total) and display in subtotal

Comment: you can create an array list and put the value of individual row in that. when + or - button is clicked you can update the value in arraylist and update the sum in activity textview.

Answer (score 1):

> Make an interface like :

```
   public interface ChangeItemInterface {

        public void doChange(float anyValue);

    }
```

**In Adapter,**

> Intialize interface object like :

```
ChangeItemInterface changeItemInterface;
```

> In Adapter Constructor,

```
this.changeItemInterface = context;
```

> In Adapter, From any View Click :

```
AnyView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 // Do total here and that value pass to the Activity via interface method like below

                 this.changeItemInterface.doChange(<AnyValue>);
                 // It will go to the Your Activity Overided method which is explained below this


            }
        });
```

> In Your Activity implement this interface like :

```
     public class YourActivity extends Activity implements ChangeItemInterface{

        /// You'll get override method of your interface, here your call back will come when from adapter click happen
         @Override
            public void doChange(float anyValue) {

              /// Here you can update any value in your activity !

              /// Here you can pass total value and update in your activity class
            }

        }
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem !